# Why is that we need constraint key word to add foreign key, but not during dropping foreign key?

Tags: mysql

While adding a foreign key this is what I use

```
ALTER TABLE grade ADD CONSTRAINT fk_grade_id FOREIGN KEY (qid) REFERENCES question(qid);
```

But to drop the foreign key, this is what I use

```
ALTER TABLE article DROP foreign key fk_grade_id;
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you choose to use alter table this way.

As mysql's documentation on [alter table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) says, the use of the constraint clause is optional if you add the foreign key:

> ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]]
>           FOREIGN KEY [index_name] (index_col_name,...)

There are multiple constraint types, not just foreign keys, using the constraint clause you can apply consistent naming convention. But this is not required when you drop the foreign key, you just reference it by its name.

Also, for whatever reason, mysql ignores the `index_name` in `alter table`, but uses the `symbol` for naming the index.